# Выделение активного пункта меню другим цветом, таким же как при Hover

Tags: html, css, меню

Сделал навбар для сайта, но не учел очень важный пункт
**(выделение активного пункта меню другим цветом, таким же как при ховере)**

Подскажите как это правильно сделать в моем случае?

Пример активного пункта меню на скриншоте [image: Пример активного пункта меню]

```css
svg{
color: #6a778e;
transition: 250ms ease all;
}
svg:hover{
color: #0b0c0f;
transform: scale(1.3);
transition: 250ms ease all;
}


#allrecords ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
}



.bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0rem;
    left: 0rem;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgb(0 0 0 / 3%);
    width: 66px;
    bottom: 0rem;
}
.navbar__link {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 3.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    color: #6a778e;
    transition: 250ms ease all;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.navbar__link span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(-3rem);
  margin-left: 1rem;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #2d43477a;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 250ms ease all;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navbar__link :hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navbar:not(:hover) .navbar__link:focus span, .navbar__link:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0);
}
.navbar__menu {
  position: relative;
}
.navbar__item:last-child:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 1rem;
  width: 3.5rem;
  height: 3.5rem;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,148,112,1) 0%, rgba(0,186,198,1) 100%);
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: 250ms cubic-bezier(1, 0.2, 0.1, 1.2) all;
}

.btn-check{
    display: none;
  }




@media (max-width: 700px) {

  .btn-check{
    display: none;
  }
  

  .main-label{
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMjQiIGhlaWdodD0iMjQiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNCAyNCIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KPHJlY3QgeD0iMiIgeT0iNSIgd2lkdGg9IjIwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjIiIHJ4PSIxIiBmaWxsPSIjMzAzODQ0Ii8+CjxyZWN0IHg9IjIiIHk9IjExIiB3aWR0aD0iMjAiIGhlaWdodD0iMiIgcng9IjEiIGZpbGw9IiMzMDM4NDQiLz4KPHJlY3QgeD0iMiIgeT0iMTciIHdpZHRoPSIyMCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyIiByeD0iMSIgZmlsbD0iIzMwMzg0NCIvPgo8L3N2Zz4K) ;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 30px;
    transition: 250ms;

  }
 
  .btn-check:checked ~ .bar{
  left: 0px;
  transition: 250ms;
}
  


.bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0rem;
    left: -7rem;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
    height: 100%;
    transition: 250ms;
}}
 
@media (min-width: 1572px) {
  .bar { 
    top: 1rem;
    bottom: 1rem;
    border-radius: 12px;
    left: 8rem;
  height: calc(100vh - 4rem);
  transition: 300ms;
  width: 85px;
  }
}


@media (min-width: 1800px) {
  .bar { 
    top: 1rem;
    bottom: 1rem;
    border-radius: 12px;
    left: 18rem;
    transition: 300ms;
    width: 85px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <label class="main-label" id="btn-check" >
  <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="btn-check" >
<nav class="bar">
  <div class="navbar__menu">
      <div class="dbltab-a_1">
      <div class="navbar__link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="28" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M8 8a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm2-3a2 2 0 1 1-4 0 2 2 0 0 1 4 0zm4 8c0 1-1 1-1 1H3s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4zm-1-.004c-.001-.246-.154-.986-.832-1.664C11.516 10.68 10.289 10 8 10c-2.29 0-3.516.68-4.168 1.332-.678.678-.83 1.418-.832 1.664h10z"/>
      </svg><span>Мой кабинет</span>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="dbltab-a_2">
      <div class="navbar__link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="28" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-eye" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M16 8s-3-5.5-8-5.5S0 8 0 8s3 5.5 8 5.5S16 8 16 8zM1.173 8a13.133 13.133 0 0 1 1.66-2.043C4.12 4.668 5.88 3.5 8 3.5c2.12 0 3.879 1.168 5.168 2.457A13.133 13.133 0 0 1 14.828 8c-.058.087-.122.183-.195.288-.335.48-.83 1.12-1.465 1.755C11.879 11.332 10.119 12.5 8 12.5c-2.12 0-3.879-1.168-5.168-2.457A13.134 13.134 0 0 1 1.172 8z"/>
        <path d="M8 5.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zM4.5 8a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1-7 0z"/>
      </svg><span>Провайдеры</span>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="dbltab-a_3">
      <div class="navbar__link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M14 1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12zM2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2z"/>
        <path d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z"/>
      </svg><span>Добавить провайдера</span>
    </div>   
  </div>  
      <div class="dbltab-a_4">
      <div class="navbar__link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-journal-check" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.854 6.146a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-1.5-1.5a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L7.5 8.793l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"/>
        <path d="M3 0h10a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-1h1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h10a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H3a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1H1V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2z"/>
        <path d="M1 5v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1zm0 3v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V8h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1zm0 3v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1z"/>
      </svg><span>Консультация</span>
    </div> 
  </div>          
      <div class="dbltab-a_5">
      <div class="navbar__link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pie-chart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M7.5 1.018a7 7 0 0 0-4.79 11.566L7.5 7.793V1.018zm1 0V7.5h6.482A7.001 7.001 0 0 0 8.5 1.018zM14.982 8.5H8.207l-4.79 4.79A7 7 0 0 0 14.982 8.5zM0 8a8 8 0 1 1 16 0A8 8 0 0 1 0 8z"/>
      </svg><span>Опросы</span>
    </div> 
  </div>      
      <div class="dbltab-a_6">
      <div class="navbar__link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-percent" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M13.442 2.558a.625.625 0 0 1 0 .884l-10 10a.625.625 0 1 1-.884-.884l10-10a.625.625 0 0 1 .884 0zM4.5 6a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm0 1a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5zm7 6a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm0 1a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5z"/>
      </svg><span>Скидки</span>
    </div>
    </div>
      <a href="#profile:edit">
      <div class="navbar__link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-gear-wide" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M8.932.727c-.243-.97-1.62-.97-1.864 0l-.071.286a.96.96 0 0 1-1.622.434l-.205-.211c-.695-.719-1.888-.03-1.613.931l.08.284a.96.96 0 0 1-1.186 1.187l-.284-.081c-.96-.275-1.65.918-.931 1.613l.211.205a.96.96 0 0 1-.434 1.622l-.286.071c-.97.243-.97 1.62 0 1.864l.286.071a.96.96 0 0 1 .434 1.622l-.211.205c-.719.695-.03 1.888.931 1.613l.284-.08a.96.96 0 0 1 1.187 1.187l-.081.283c-.275.96.918 1.65 1.613.931l.205-.211a.96.96 0 0 1 1.622.434l.071.286c.243.97 1.62.97 1.864 0l.071-.286a.96.96 0 0 1 1.622-.434l.205.211c.695.719 1.888.03 1.613-.931l-.08-.284a.96.96 0 0 1 1.187-1.187l.283.081c.96.275 1.65-.918.931-1.613l-.211-.205a.96.96 0 0 1 .434-1.622l.286-.071c.97-.243.97-1.62 0-1.864l-.286-.071a.96.96 0 0 1-.434-1.622l.211-.205c.719-.695.03-1.888-.931-1.613l-.284.08a.96.96 0 0 1-1.187-1.186l.081-.284c.275-.96-.918-1.65-1.613-.931l-.205.211a.96.96 0 0 1-1.622-.434L8.932.727zM8 12.997a4.998 4.998 0 1 1 0-9.995 4.998 4.998 0 0 1 0 9.996z"/>
</svg><span>Настройки</span>
    </div>
      <a href="#logout">
      <div class="navbar__link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-box-arrow-right" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 12.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-8a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0v-2A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 9.5 2h-8A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3.5v9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 14h8a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-2a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v2z"/>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M15.854 8.354a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708.708L14.293 7.5H5.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h8.793l-2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708l3-3z"/>
</svg><span>Выход</span>
    </div>
        </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так?

При клике на блок сначала проверяеться если существует элемент с классом `active-svg`, если сущечтвует то убирает у него класс, ксли такого нет то идёт дальше. Потом просто присваивает элементу на который вы нажали класс `active-svg`.

Вот и всё логика

```js
const menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar__link');

for (elem of menuLinks) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let activeSvg = document.querySelector('.active-svg');
    if (activeSvg != null) activeSvg.classList.remove('active-svg');
    this.classList.add('active-svg');
  })
}
```

```css
svg {
  color: #6a778e;
  transition: 250ms ease all;
}

.active-svg svg,
svg:hover {
  color: #0b0c0f;
  transform: scale(1.3);
  transition: 250ms ease all;
}

#allrecords ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0rem;
  left: 0rem;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgb(0 0 0 / 3%);
  width: 66px;
  bottom: 0rem;
}

.navbar__link {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  color: #6a778e;
  transition: 250ms ease all;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar__link span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(-3rem);
  margin-left: 1rem;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #2d43477a;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 250ms ease all;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar__link :hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar:not(:hover) .navbar__link:focus span,
.navbar__link:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0);
}

.navbar__menu {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar__item:last-child:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 1rem;
  width: 3.5rem;
  height: 3.5rem;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 148, 112, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 186, 198, 1) 100%);
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: 250ms cubic-bezier(1, 0.2, 0.1, 1.2) all;
}

.btn-check {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .btn-check {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-label {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMjQiIGhlaWdodD0iMjQiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNCAyNCIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KPHJlY3QgeD0iMiIgeT0iNSIgd2lkdGg9IjIwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjIiIHJ4PSIxIiBmaWxsPSIjMzAzODQ0Ii8+CjxyZWN0IHg9IjIiIHk9IjExIiB3aWR0aD0iMjAiIGhlaWdodD0iMiIgcng9IjEiIGZpbGw9IiMzMDM4NDQiLz4KPHJlY3QgeD0iMiIgeT0iMTciIHdpZHRoPSIyMCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyIiByeD0iMSIgZmlsbD0iIzMwMzg0NCIvPgo8L3N2Zz4K);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 30px;
    transition: 250ms;
  }
  .btn-check:checked~.bar {
    left: 0px;
    transition: 250ms;
  }
  .bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0rem;
    left: -7rem;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
    height: 100%;
    transition: 250ms;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1572px) {
  .bar {
    top: 1rem;
    bottom: 1rem;
    border-radius: 12px;
    left: 8rem;
    height: calc(100vh - 4rem);
    transition: 300ms;
    width: 85px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1800px) {
  .bar {
    top: 1rem;
    bottom: 1rem;
    border-radius: 12px;
    left: 18rem;
    transition: 300ms;
    width: 85px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <label class="main-label" id="btn-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="btn-check" >
<nav class="bar">
  <div class="navbar__menu">
      <div class="dbltab-a_1">
      <div class="navbar__link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="28" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M8 8a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm2-3a2 2 0 1 1-4 0 2 2 0 0 1 4 0zm4 8c0 1-1 1-1 1H3s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4zm-1-.004c-.001-.246-.154-.986-.832-1.664C11.516 10.68 10.289 10 8 10c-2.29 0-3.516.68-4.168 1.332-.678.678-.83 1.418-.832 1.664h10z"/>
      </svg><span>Мой кабинет</span>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="dbltab-a_2">
      <div class="navbar__link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="28" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-eye" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M16 8s-3-5.5-8-5.5S0 8 0 8s3 5.5 8 5.5S16 8 16 8zM1.173 8a13.133 13.133 0 0 1 1.66-2.043C4.12 4.668 5.88 3.5 8 3.5c2.12 0 3.879 1.168 5.168 2.457A13.133 13.133 0 0 1 14.828 8c-.058.087-.122.183-.195.288-.335.48-.83 1.12-1.465 1.755C11.879 11.332 10.119 12.5 8 12.5c-2.12 0-3.879-1.168-5.168-2.457A13.134 13.134 0 0 1 1.172 8z"/>
        <path d="M8 5.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zM4.5 8a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1-7 0z"/>
      </svg><span>Провайдеры</span>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="dbltab-a_3">
      <div class="navbar__link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M14 1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12zM2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2z"/>
        <path d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z"/>
      </svg><span>Добавить провайдера</span>
    </div>   
  </div>  
      <div class="dbltab-a_4">
      <div class="navbar__link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-journal-check" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.854 6.146a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-1.5-1.5a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L7.5 8.793l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"/>
        <path d="M3 0h10a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-1h1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h10a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H3a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1H1V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2z"/>
        <path d="M1 5v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1zm0 3v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V8h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1zm0 3v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1z"/>
      </svg><span>Консультация</span>
    </div> 
  </div>          
      <div class="dbltab-a_5">
      <div class="navbar__link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pie-chart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M7.5 1.018a7 7 0 0 0-4.79 11.566L7.5 7.793V1.018zm1 0V7.5h6.482A7.001 7.001 0 0 0 8.5 1.018zM14.982 8.5H8.207l-4.79 4.79A7 7 0 0 0 14.982 8.5zM0 8a8 8 0 1 1 16 0A8 8 0 0 1 0 8z"/>
      </svg><span>Опросы</span>
    </div> 
  </div>      
      <div class="dbltab-a_6">
      <div class="navbar__link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-percent" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M13.442 2.558a.625.625 0 0 1 0 .884l-10 10a.625.625 0 1 1-.884-.884l10-10a.625.625 0 0 1 .884 0zM4.5 6a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm0 1a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5zm7 6a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm0 1a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5z"/>
      </svg><span>Скидки</span>
    </div>
    </div>
      <a href="#profile:edit">
      <div class="navbar__link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-gear-wide" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M8.932.727c-.243-.97-1.62-.97-1.864 0l-.071.286a.96.96 0 0 1-1.622.434l-.205-.211c-.695-.719-1.888-.03-1.613.931l.08.284a.96.96 0 0 1-1.186 1.187l-.284-.081c-.96-.275-1.65.918-.931 1.613l.211.205a.96.96 0 0 1-.434 1.622l-.286.071c-.97.243-.97 1.62 0 1.864l.286.071a.96.96 0 0 1 .434 1.622l-.211.205c-.719.695-.03 1.888.931 1.613l.284-.08a.96.96 0 0 1 1.187 1.187l-.081.283c-.275.96.918 1.65 1.613.931l.205-.211a.96.96 0 0 1 1.622.434l.071.286c.243.97 1.62.97 1.864 0l.071-.286a.96.96 0 0 1 1.622-.434l.205.211c.695.719 1.888.03 1.613-.931l-.08-.284a.96.96 0 0 1 1.187-1.187l.283.081c.96.275 1.65-.918.931-1.613l-.211-.205a.96.96 0 0 1 .434-1.622l.286-.071c.97-.243.97-1.62 0-1.864l-.286-.071a.96.96 0 0 1-.434-1.622l.211-.205c.719-.695.03-1.888-.931-1.613l-.284.08a.96.96 0 0 1-1.187-1.186l.081-.284c.275-.96-.918-1.65-1.613-.931l-.205.211a.96.96 0 0 1-1.622-.434L8.932.727zM8 12.997a4.998 4.998 0 1 1 0-9.995 4.998 4.998 0 0 1 0 9.996z"/>
</svg><span>Настройки</span>
    </div>
      <a href="#logout">
      <div class="navbar__link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-box-arrow-right" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 12.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-8a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0v-2A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 9.5 2h-8A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3.5v9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 14h8a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-2a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v2z"/>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M15.854 8.354a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708.708L14.293 7.5H5.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h8.793l-2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708l3-3z"/>
</svg><span>Выход</span>
    </div>
        </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Реально ли провернуть это без JS?

Comment: @glasswalk наверное как-то можно, но это не в моих силах